# Find and merge a list of key-combinations based on certain criterion - Javascript

Tags: javascript

My input list:

Task is to loop through the input list given below and find a final output which merges the list 'values' with the following merge strategy.

1. Primary key is a combination of the following keys `code+brc+dest`. If any of the values in other indexes of the list match this key, we need to check the type and return the most restrictive type ( in my case 'HARD' ).

For Example :

```
 index 0   value : `[{ "code": 1,"brc":"ABC","dest":"des1","type":"SOFT"}]`
 index 1   value  : `[{ "code": 1,"brc":"ABC","dest":"des1","type":"HARD"}],`
 index 2   value : `[{ "code": 1,"brc":"ABC","dest":"des1","type":"SOFT"}],`
```

As the combination `code + brc + des1` combination matches in the value of index 0 of the list matches with value at index 1 , we check for the most restrictive type ( in this case hard ). We also check for the same combination-key at other index's and give the final output as below

```
 output : `[{ "code": 1,"brc":"ABC","dest":"des1","type":"HARD"}],`
```

2. If there are excess elements in any of the values that don't have any matching elements with any keys , we have to return them. ( Examples from the below input list are elements with `code:5 and code: 6` ) which are a part of the final list.

Below is the complete input, we have to loop through the list get the `value` from the list index 0 and compare this combination-key with all the values at other index's in this list and merge them accordingly.

```
let data =  [{
      "id":1,
      "value":[
         {
            "code": 1,
            "brc":"abc",
            "dest":"des1",
            "type":"SOFT"
         },
         {
            "code": 2,
            "brc":"def",
            "dest":"des2",
            "type":"HARD"
         },
         {
            "code": 3,
            "brc":"ghi",
            "dest":"des3",
            "type":"SOFT"
         },
         {
            "code": 4,
            "brc":"jkl",
            "dest":"des4",
            "type":"SOFT"
         },
         {
            "code": 5,
            "brc":"mno",
            "dest":"des5",
            "type":"SOFT"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "value":[
         {
            "code": 1,
            "brc":"abc",
            "dest":"des1",
            "type":"HARD"
         },
         {
           "code":2 ,
            "brc":"def",
            "dest":"des2",
            "type":"HARD"
         },
         {
           "code": 3,
            "brc":"ghi",
            "dest":"des3",
            "type":"HARD"
         },
         {
           "code": 4,
            "brc":"jkl",
            "dest":"des4",
            "type":"SOFT"
         },
         {
           "code": 6,
            "brc":"pqr",
            "dest":"des6",
            "type":"SOFT"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "value":[
         {
           "code": 1,
            "brc":"abc",
            "dest":"des1",
            "type":"SOFT"
         },
         {
           "code": 2,
            "brc":"def",
            "dest":"des2",
            "type":"HARD"
         },
         {
           "code": 3,
            "brc":"ghi",
            "dest":"des3",
            "type":"SOFT"
         },
         {
           "code": 4,
            "brc":"jkl",
            "dest":"des4",
            "type":"SOFT",
           "extra": "shouldpersisit"
         },
      ]
   }
];
```

Output :

```
 [{
            "code": 1,
            "brc":"abc",
            "dest":"des1",
            "type":"HARD"
         },
         {
            "code": 2,
            "brc":"def",
            "dest":"des2",
            "type":"HARD"
         },
         {
            "code": 3,
            "brc":"ghi",
            "dest":"des3",
            "type":"HARD"
         },
         {
            "code": 4,
            "brc":"jkl",
            "dest":"des4",
            "type":"SOFT"
         },
         {
            "code": 4,
            "brc":"jkl",
            "dest":"des4",
            "type":"SOFT"
         },
         {
            "code": 5,
            "brc":"mno",
            "dest":"des5",
            "type":"SOFT"
         },
         {
           "code": 6,
            "brc":"pqr",
            "dest":"des6",
            "type":"SOFT"
         }
         
 ]
```

I've written pseudo code, but I felt I am already 4 loops deep inside and this for sure increases the time for computation.  ( I am not forming the final list yet in this function , but will eventually return the Output as shown above for the input given ).

```
function doMerge(inputData){

inputData.forEach((data,index) => { 

  // loop through input list 

  data.value.forEach(innerData => {

    // looping through the value key in the list and form the combination key for the first item in the value


       const concatKey = `${innerData.code}${innerData.brc}${innerData.dest}`;

    
      // loop through the total inputData again to go through each index's value and check for the key combination
      // once key combination is found, find the 'type' of that object and save the most restricted out of the both.
      // exit from that list ( hence using `some` ) 
      // move on to all other items in the input Data . 


       inputData.forEach(allItems => {
          
            let finalType = '';
         
         allItems.value.some(item => {
            const innerConcatKey = `${item.code}${item.brc}${item.dest}`;
           

             if(concatKey === innerConcatKey){
               finalType = loopDataInner.type === 'HARD'  ? 'HARD' : 'SOFT';
               return true;
             }
         });
       });
  });
});
}
```

doMerge(data);

Comment: What do you mean with "more restrictive type" do you mean that HARD has a preference over SOFT?

Comment: @F-nixro yes that's right. Sorry for not getting into those details in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to acomplish this is using a dictionaries to store your key/values, store them on an array gives the code more complexity than desire, on Javascript you can use dictionaries in two ways: using an object or a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object.

I've created a code to illustrate what I mean:

```js
function doMerge(data = []) {
    // We create a flat array only with the entries from value prop
    const flattenedData = data.reduce((acc,el) => {
        acc.push(...el.value);
        return acc;
    },[]);
    //MergeData will be our main dict
    const mergeData = new Map();

    flattenedData.forEach(element => {
        const {code,brc,dest,type} = element;
        const key = `${code}-${brc}-${dest}`
        if(mergeData.has(key)) {
            if(type === 'HARD') {
                //We only update if the type is HARD
                mergeData.set(key,element);
            }
        } else {
            mergeData.set(key,element);
        }
    });

    const elements = [];
    for (let value of mergeData.values()){
        elements.push(value);
    }

    return elements;
}


let data =  [{
    "id":1,
    "value":[
       {
          "code": 1,
          "brc":"abc",
          "dest":"des1",
          "type":"SOFT"
       },
       {
          "code": 2,
          "brc":"def",
          "dest":"des2",
          "type":"HARD"
       },
       {
          "code": 3,
          "brc":"ghi",
          "dest":"des3",
          "type":"SOFT"
       },
       {
          "code": 4,
          "brc":"jkl",
          "dest":"des4",
          "type":"SOFT"
       },
       {
          "code": 5,
          "brc":"mno",
          "dest":"des5",
          "type":"SOFT"
       }
    ]
 },
 {
    "id":2,
    "value":[
       {
          "code": 1,
          "brc":"abc",
          "dest":"des1",
          "type":"HARD"
       },
       {
         "code":2 ,
          "brc":"def",
          "dest":"des2",
          "type":"HARD"
       },
       {
         "code": 3,
          "brc":"ghi",
          "dest":"des3",
          "type":"HARD"
       },
       {
         "code": 4,
          "brc":"jkl",
          "dest":"des4",
          "type":"SOFT"
       },
       {
         "code": 6,
          "brc":"pqr",
          "dest":"des6",
          "type":"SOFT"
       }
    ]
 },
 {
    "id":3,
    "value":[
       {
         "code": 1,
          "brc":"abc",
          "dest":"des1",
          "type":"SOFT"
       },
       {
         "code": 2,
          "brc":"def",
          "dest":"des2",
          "type":"HARD"
       },
       {
         "code": 3,
          "brc":"ghi",
          "dest":"des3",
          "type":"SOFT"
       },
       {
         "code": 4,
          "brc":"jkl",
          "dest":"des4",
          "type":"SOFT",
         "extra": "shouldpersisit"
       },
    ]
 }
];

const result = doMerge(data);

console.log(result);
```

There you can see that we need three operations with arrays:

1. First we create a flat array only with the values from the main data.
2. We iterate through the flat array and store the value if it doesn't exists and update the value if it exists but the new type is HARD (since it has priority).
3. The last thing is iterate on the Map object to retrieve the data as an array.

Comment: thanks, I will check how this fares with more than 200 rows of data ( which is the case I need ).

Comment: I am just coming back to this question because I am intrigued by your thought process to create a dictionary to solve this question. If you don't mind can you let me know how I can train myself to solve such problems in JS ?  It would be really helpful. Thanks!